# 2 Versions of charts.js in single page for dark mode

Tags: chart.js

I have used 2 versions of charts.js on my HTML page. First I used v2, then I realized there is no offset property for the pie chart in v2, so I also used v3 for that pie chart. First I declared v2 charts.js for my other charts and then I declared the script file for v3 and then the pie chart. It works correctly, except for the fact that I have a dark mode toggle on my website.

How do I change the label colors for both versions of charts with my dark mode toggle? Please help.

Right now, I am only able to change the color for version 3 of the charts.js pie chart.